# GNU Parallel not improving performance

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

I have the following script which zip archives a series of files/directories in the current directory in parallel and stores the archives into a temp directory.

```
# cd into a directory

tmp_directory="/tmp/test-1"

mkdir "${tmp_directory}" && \
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | \
parallel -j $(parallel --number-of-cores) zip -r ${tmp_directory}/{/.}.zip {} && \
zipmerge -k ../test-1.zip $tmp_directory

# a zip archive called test-1.zip should be generated at ../ #relative to the current directory
```

Note that to run the above code, GNU parallel and zipmerge must be installed.

The problem is that the sequential speed, before using parallel when zipping the directory is faster than after. The process is definitely not IO bound- checking h(top), the CPU is at 100% and the read/write speeds are ver low i.e. 10MB/s. I'm running this on an 8-core machine.

One thing is that when I first start the script, the CPU on 4 cores jumps to 100% and then drops rapidly until only one core is fully utilized.

I have no idea why it's not speeding up.

EDIT: iostat output (M2 MacBook Air)

```
disk0 
    KB/t  tps  MB/s 
   25.62    4  0.10 
    8.00    8  0.06 
    8.00    8  0.06 
    0.00    0  0.00 
    0.00    0  0.00 
    0.00    0  0.00 
   84.55 1323 109.22 
  727.63  117 83.47 
  228.24  249 55.44 
  955.80   60 55.74 
  927.55   53 47.76 
  870.12   66 55.97 
  925.10   62 55.85 
  398.56  171 66.60 
  241.23  362 85.31 
  428.89 1925 806.33 
  180.50  765 134.81 
    4.46   95  0.41 
    6.13   15  0.09
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like it is extracted from a recipe in a makefile.  Although it probably won't improve speed, it will simplify the question if you convert to a standalone shell command.

Comment: Is `${tmp_directory}` inside the directory tree rooted at the current working directory?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's not from a makefile. tmp_directory is defined in the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: Then why are you escaping the `$` in `\$(parallel --number-of-cores)`, and why does the command do unnecessary line-joining?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The program I was using it in was using `eval`.

Comment: Fine.  Same thing then: the question would be improved by presenting a standalone command.  Or if you don't want to do that then at least present a *whole* command (what is presented is not whole without the `eval`).  And note that `eval` is very tricky to use correctly.  You are almost always better off avoiding it.

Comment: I've added the temp directory. What do you mean as a standalone command? Apologies if I've misunderstood @JohnBollinger. The main reason I was using `eval` was that I needed to store the above in a variable so I could run it and pass it as an argument to another command.

Comment: By "standalone" I mean something that I could copy verbatim into my shell, and it would mean the same thing there as it does in the context where you were running it.  It looks like you've now come close enough to that.

Comment: I think `--number-of-cores` just tells you how many cores you have rather than actually doing anything.

Comment: @MarkSetchell But I'm evaluating it to go with the `-j` flag. Even if I replace it with a number e.g. `4` or `8`, I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Ok - please click [edit] and make sure your [mcve] shows the actual code you are running.

Comment: I've added comments and included the full code. Running the above code in any directory should produce a zip file in the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds I/O bound.

```
iostat -dkx 1
```

is excellent for seeing how busy a disk is. However much I love `top`, it is useless for this.

Your problem is likely not bandwidth, but seeking.

On magnetic drives it will often be faster to read sequentially than in parallel. NVMe drives typically have a sweet spot of parallelization (often 4 or 8). RAID and network drives will often also have a sweet spot, but it depends on the drive.

PS: `parallel -j $(parallel --number-of-cores)` is the same as `parallel --use-cores-instead-of-threads`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. When I run `iostat`, it doesn't show a utilisation value on Mac. I've added what I see to the question. Is there a way of measuring the amount of seeking? Or even a way of minimizing the amount of seeking? I would have expected at least some performance boost from reading files and compressing in parallel.

Comment: @testing09 I currently do not have access to a mac, but I have made `iostat` show the ultilization percentage. So look at `man iostat` and see if you can find the option I used.